# How do I correct images that are stretching disproportionately when the DIV class containing it is sized correctly?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, elementor

I'm currently working on a timeline module (Elementor/Wordpress) and although the image is uploaded correctly, displays correctly in the Wordpress gallery, and shows the correct proportions there, it's ultimately displaying wrong.

The div class is `<div class="eael-content-timeline-img eael-picture">` and in the Inspector I can hover over it and see the dimensions are correct (In this case 60x60). However, when I hover over the img src, I can see the dimensions are skewed (60x24) and I'm unsure where those numbers are coming from because it's nothing that I've set through the builder.

[Screenshot of the stretching and my view from Chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwj8g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the aspect ratio of the image is preserved and the image does not get stretched, apply the following `CSS`, targeting the `img` inside the `div`:

```css
.eael-content-timeline-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That ended up solving the problem, I just had to tweak the class I was targeting and use 'eael-content-timeline-img img {  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}'